# Android bluetooth fluoride stack build

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to build Android BT stack fluoride using [this instruction](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/bt/+/android-8.0.0_r10/README.md) on Ubuntu 16.04 and clang 3.8.0 on Virtual Machine Virtual Box. Everything goes well until I run command "ninja -C out/Default all". It was building fluoride few days and did not finish. The build log is:

`log: ninja version 0.1.3 initializing
    log: magic group: gid=0 (root)
    log: entering main loop
    log: generating initial pid array..
    log: now monitoring process activity
    log: NEW ROOT PROCESS: sudo[3736] ppid=3721 uid=0 gid=1000
    log:   - ppid uid=1000(olga) gid=1000 ppid=3442
    log:   + olga is in magic group, all OK!
    log: NEW ROOT PROCESS: aptd[4541] ppid=4540 uid=0 gid=0
    log:   - ppid uid=106(messagebus) gid=110 ppid=564
    log:   + messagebus is in magic group, all OK!`

What the problem is? How long your fluoride building lasts?